# Spring Logs are NOT named properly in Spring Boot App

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, config

In Spring Boot App with Gradle.

[image]

Below is my **application yml** file

```
server:
  tomcat:
    connectionTimeout: 300000
management:
  endpoint:
    mappings:
      enabled: true
spring:
  liquibase:
    change-log: classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
    hikari:
      minimum-idle: 5
      maximumPoolSize: 20
      idleTimeout: 30000
      maxLifetime: 2000000
      connectionTimeout: 30000
      poolName: data-pool
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      use-new-id-generator-mappings: false
      ddl-auto: none
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
```

Below is my **logback-spring.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration>
<configuration>

    <springProperty scope="context" name="app_name" source="spring.application.name"/>
    <springProperty scope="context" name="environment" source="param_env" defaultValue="default_env"/>
    <springProperty scope="context" name="tenant" source="param_tenant" defaultValue="default_tenant"/>

    <property name="GENERIC_PATTERN"
              value="[%date{ISO8601}] [%p] [%t] [%c{2}] %4L | %m%n"/>
    <property name="CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN" value="$GENERIC_PATTERN"/>
    <property name="CHARSET" value="UTF-8"/>

    <property name="LOG_DIR"
              value="logs/${envname:-${environment}}/${param_dtlogname:-${app_name}}"/>

        <appender name="API_FILE_APPENDER" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">

            <file>${LOG_DIR}/api-${param_dtlogname}-${HOSTNAME}.log</file>
            <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
                <!-- daily rollover -->
                <fileNamePattern>
                    ${LOG_DIR}/api-${param_dtlogname}-${HOSTNAME}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
                </fileNamePattern>
            </rollingPolicy>
        </appender> 
        <appender name="APPLICATION_FILE_APPENDER" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">

            <file>${LOG_DIR}/startup-${param_dtlogname}-${HOSTNAME}.log</file>
    
        </appender>
    </springProfile>
</configuration>
```

below is my **bootstrap.yml file**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: doctors-data
```

**I am facing 2 issues :**

**1.** 1st Issue is when I see the logs that I got from my team mate, Logs has lot of **IS_UNDEFINED** word in it like below.  why am I getting **IS_UNDEFINED** word ?

[image]

**2.** 2nd Issue is I am not sure in intellij or my system where does these logs are getting generated ?, not able to find the location in my system.

I believe the issue can be in `name="app_name" source="spring.application.name"` so may be I can try with `${spring.application.name}` but **major issue is I am not** able to see default location where logs are getting generated. once I see where do logs reside then I can try with `${spring.application.name}` currently I am not even able to verify the hit and trial approach.

Can someone please guide me on above mentioned issues ?

Comment: Why do you ask [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73205906/logs-name-is-not-coming-properly-got-undefined-word-in-logs-name-of-spring) again as a different user!

Comment: My Teammate is there, we two are working on same project. so may be he has not seen my question on SO, will ask him to not ask again. he was also eagerly looking for the solutions. thanks.

Comment: Since your LOG_DIR is a relative path IntelliJ would write the _logs_ directroy into the working directory of your runconfiguration. By default this is either your IntelliJ project root directory or the module directory. Also, the filename seems to tell you the problem `param_dtlogname_IS_UNDEFINED`. When you specify the filename in the config you use the `${param_dtlogname}`, which seems to be undefined.